# Editing contents of a listbox that is populated by a sql query datasource using c#

Tags: c#, sql, listbox, datasource, edit

I have a list box that is populated by a query result set, i would to give the user the ability to edit the contents of the list box, and update the database back end, how can i achieve this?

```
public Brand_Manager(Main parent)
{
SqlConnection conn = new     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Brand_ID, Brand_Name from Brand where status=1", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(t);
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Brand_Name";
        listBox1.DataSource = t;
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Brand_ID";

        conn.Close();
}
 private void Edit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Edit_Button.Enabled = false;
        object item = listBox1.SelectedItem;
         Edit_Brand frm = new Edit_Brand();
        this.AddOwnedForm(frm);
        frm.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use datagridview for this purpose. It is designed for this purpose. You can assign the datasource to gridview and allow user to edit rows. Then by handling row edited event or by giving the button you can update the database.  See an example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfdfde62-c32c-4952-aa7f-e98fa60e1fbb/update-database-table-when-datagrid-view-cell-value-changed)

Comment: would u mind demonstrating how this would be implemented using datagridview, also, are you saying its not possible with a list box? Thanks for your help.

Comment: well i will not say it is not possible with listbox but not out of the box. Drag a gridview to your form assign it this datasource. See the details here http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread6724-insert-update-delete-with-datagridview-control-in-csharp-windows-applic.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you use WPF or WinForms? Anyway you need to investigate `Bindings`: `BindingSource` in WinForms or `Binding` class in WPF (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx).

Comment: Can't help you quick because i'm don't use WinForms for a long time, sorry. But **Bindings** is the case you need to examine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at DataTable events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable_events.aspx . There is RowChangedEvent. Call update sql command in its handler.